# How does one take birth as a dakini, shakini, yakshini, yogini?

Tags: durga, kali, birth

Related to the other question I posted about what comes after human life.

Just wondering what are the requirements to be born as dakini/shakini or as a yogini or yakshini ?

What makes someone born in that yoni ?

The chausath yogini are considered directly beneath Kali/Durga and the dakini shakini beings are always shown as being with Kali.

So assuming a benevolent nature, seems like a good birth for someone who is a devotee of Devi ?

Comment: In the realms of tantra, these are human subtle body only. After death what one becomes - ghost, pisacha, yaksha, vetal, etc. depends largely on chakras, nadis and their activation/balancing after death. If you wish to know the puranic answer, please do specify, otherwise I'll skip over technical terms.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Thanks ! Curious to know both the puranic answer and the more technical answer, for this. Some of these beings (yogini and yakshini type) seem to be able to take human form when they want.

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve. In the usual sense, they don't need to *appear* in your eyes to exist. For example - *Karnapisachini Sadhana* (yakshas) is a very tamasic sadhana where these entities don't necessarily appear before you, but your ears would start buzzing by themselves. They don't necessarily appear, most of the time can be dismissed as *Hallucinations*.

Comment: Ghosts are **not** able to take human bodies, they just take **mind-made** bodies. The mind-made body has nothing to do with physical ones. That's why you don't see physical nude ghosts, but wearing clothes over them.

Comment: @User29449 Thank you

Comment: One doesn't take birth as Yogini, dakini, shakini. It's based on how much an upasaka is realized, he get's the state. For example usually in VajraKula & Chinnachara, the upasaka enters Daikini state and become one with that, in Kali kula the upasaka as veera may enter into state of Yogini... Likewise, with Shakini.

Comment: @Chamundadas Oh ! Ok. I didn’t realize that. I’ve been reading and reading and reading. And came across contradictory statements as to how jiva are brought to higher level plane of existence. Some texts say reincarnation and others say something different. Thanks for replying with your comments ! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Higher planes or being is based on how much one progresses in upasana. For example Ramakrishna Paramhamsa and Sharda mata themselves have realized the state of Dakini and Varini. For some it's a दशा one realizes, for few upasakas they after leaving mortal still continues to roam around as Dakinis and Yoginis of her churnel ground. So, the final say is how much one does progress in upasana.

Comment: @Chamundadas Thanks so much, that makes sense